# Use of undefined constant admin - assumed 'admin' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Tags: php, laravel

this is the admin routes

```
Route::get('admin/home', 'AdminController@index');
Route::get('admin', 'Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login.admin');
Route::post('admin', 'Admin\LoginController@login');
```

LoginController

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
}

public function showLoginForm() {
    return view('admin.login');
}

/**
 * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
 */
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('admin');
}
```

layouts blade

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('login.admin') }}">
                                    admin login
                                </a>
```

if someone need to see more code to understand the error please comment

Comment: Please post the exact line that the error refers to.

Comment: The code you've shown could not have caused this warning. The error specifies both file and line where this is happening. It will most likely be an unquoted string.

Comment: ErrorException
Use of undefined constant admin - assumed 'admin' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
http://localhost:8000/admin
thats all i got i have no error line

Comment: the problem solved it was unquoted string